# Append addition elements to React form using reactstrap

Tags: javascript, html, forms, reactjs, reactstrap

I have started with a form using `reactstrap` and have a scenario where I have multiple checkboxes. With that, if I checkbox is selected, I want to append a `textarea` just below it. Having difficulty in figuring this out within a single component.

In addition, I have tried to append tooltips to another area of my form using `reactstrap` where I got similar messed up results. With this piece (seems similar situation as with the checkboxes with `textarea`), all the tooltips apply to the first `anchor` tag as shown in the image below the code.

My code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  Route,
  NavLink,
  HashRouter
} from "react-router-dom";
import {
  Container,
  Card,
  CardText,
  CardImg,
  CardBody,
  CardTitle,
    Button,
    Form,
    FormGroup,
    Label,
    Input,
    FormText,
    Tooltip,
    Col,
  Row } from 'reactstrap'
import Users from "./Users";
import './ConnCust.css';


class ConnCust extends Component {

constructor(props) {
            super(props);

            this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
            this.state = {
                tooltipOpen: false
            };
        }

        toggle() {
            this.setState({
                tooltipOpen: !this.state.tooltipOpen
            });
        }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Container>
                    <Row>
                        <h2>Need help finding customers?</h2>
                    </Row>
          <Row>
                        <p>Please fill out the fields below to enable us to find the best matches for your requests.</p>
          </Row>
                    <Row>
                        <p>Note: Please be as specific and detailed as possible.</p>
          </Row>
          <Row>
                        <Form>
                            <FormGroup check>
                                <Label check>
                                    <Input type="checkbox" />{' '}
                                    Work with customers for product/service feedback
                                </Label>
                            </FormGroup>
                            <FormGroup>
                                <Input type="textarea" name="text" id="cust1text" placeholder="please provide additional information if needed"/>
                            </FormGroup>
                            <FormGroup check>
                                <Label check>
                                    <Input type="checkbox" />{' '}
                                    Get help with the research activity (build a survey, run experiments, analyze results, run usability or pilot studies, etc.)
                                </Label>
                            </FormGroup>
                            <FormGroup>
                                <Input type="textarea" name="text" id="cust1text" placeholder="please provide additional information if needed"/>
                            </FormGroup>
                            <FormGroup check>
                                <Label check>
                                    <Input type="checkbox" />{' '}
                                    Validate new product/service ideas
                                </Label>
                            </FormGroup>
                            <FormGroup>
                                <Input type="textarea" name="text" id="cust1text" placeholder="please provide additional information if needed"/>
                            </FormGroup>
                            <FormGroup check>
                                <Label check>
                                    <Input type="checkbox" />{' '}
                                    Need assistance in Scheduling Customer Feedback meetings
                                </Label>
                            </FormGroup>
                            <FormGroup>
                                <Input type="textarea" name="text" id="cust1text" placeholder="please provide additional information if needed"/>
                            </FormGroup>
                            <FormGroup check>
                                <Label check>
                                    <Input type="checkbox" />{' '}
                                    Conduct Customer visit in person (Immerse)
                                </Label>
                            </FormGroup>
                            <FormGroup>
                                <Input type="textarea" name="text" id="cust1text" placeholder="please provide additional information if needed"/>
                            </FormGroup>
                            <FormGroup check>
                                <Label check>
                                    <Input type="checkbox" />{' '}
                                    Conduct customer visit remotely (Immerse)
                                </Label>
                            </FormGroup>
                            <FormGroup>
                                <Input type="textarea" name="text" id="cust1text" placeholder="please provide additional information if needed"/>
                            </FormGroup>
                            <FormGroup>
                                <Label for="custNumber">Total Number of Customers Needed</Label>
                                <Input type="text" name="custNumber" id="custNumber" placeholder="any range from 1 to 99" />
                            </FormGroup>
                            <FormGroup>
                                <Label for="custType">What type of customers/job titles/roles are you looking for? (e.g. BI Analyst, CEO, Data Scientists, Network Administrators, DevOps etc.)?</Label>
                            </FormGroup>
                            <FormGroup check>
                                <Label check>
                                    <Input type="checkbox" />{' '}
                                    <a href="#" id="custType1">Administrators</a>
                                    <Tooltip placement="right" isOpen={this.state.tooltipOpen} target="custType1" toggle={this.toggle}>
                                        Computer support, computer systems, Database, IT, Network, Web
                                    </Tooltip>
                                </Label>
                            </FormGroup>
                            <FormGroup check>
                                <Label check>
                                    <Input type="checkbox" />{' '}
                                    <a href="#" id="custType2">Analysts</a>
                                    <Tooltip placement="left" isOpen={this.state.tooltipOpen} target="custType2" toggle={this.toggle}>
                                        Business, Infrastructure, Information Systems, Information Security, IT, PowerBI, Support, Software Quality Assurance, Systems, Web analytics
                                    </Tooltip>
                                </Label>
                            </FormGroup>
                            <FormGroup check>
                                <Label check>
                                    <Input type="checkbox" />{' '}
                                    Architects
                                </Label>
                            </FormGroup>
                            <FormGroup check>
                                <Label check>
                                    <Input type="checkbox" />{' '}
                                    Developers and Dev-Ops
                                </Label>
                            </FormGroup>
                            <FormGroup check>
                                <Label check>
                                    <Input type="checkbox" />{' '}
                                    Engineers
                                </Label>
                            </FormGroup>
                            <FormGroup check>
                                <Label check>
                                    <Input type="checkbox" />{' '}
                                    Managers
                                </Label>
                            </FormGroup>
                            <FormGroup check>
                                <Label check>
                                    <Input type="checkbox" />{' '}
                                    Marketing and Sales
                                </Label>
                            </FormGroup>
                            <FormGroup check>
                                <Label check>
                                    <Input type="checkbox" />{' '}
                                    Scientists
                                </Label>
                            </FormGroup>
                            <FormGroup check>
                                <Label check>
                                    <Input type="checkbox" />{' '}
                                    Executives
                                </Label>
                            </FormGroup>
                            <FormGroup check>
                                <Label check>
                                    <Input type="checkbox" />{' '}
                                    Other
                                </Label>
                            </FormGroup>
                            <FormGroup>
                                <Label for="exampleSelect">Is a Non-Disclosure Agreement (NDA) required for this Request?</Label>
                                <Input type="select" name="ndaOpt" id="ndaOpt">
                                    <option></option>
                                    <option>yes</option>
                                    <option>no</option>
                                    <option>not sure</option>
                                </Input>
                            </FormGroup>
                            <FormGroup>
                                <Label for="custType">Please list if you have any Customers/companies in mind for this Request?</Label>
                                <Input type="text" name="text" id="cust1text" placeholder="(e.g. DocuSign, GE, GEICO, Rackspace, Wal-Mart etc.)"/>
                            </FormGroup>
                            <FormGroup>
                                <Label for="custType">What technology would you like Customers from?</Label>
                                <Input type="text" name="text" id="cust1text" placeholder="(e.g. Azure, OMS, SQL Server, O365.)"/>
                            </FormGroup>
                            <FormGroup>
                                <Label for="custType">What industry or vertical you would like your customers from?</Label>
                                <Input type="text" name="text" id="cust1text" placeholder="(e.g. Banking, Health Care, Retail, Service Providers etc.)"/>
                            </FormGroup>
                            <FormGroup>
                                <Label for="custType">Are there any geographies (regions/countries) you would like customers from?</Label>
                            </FormGroup>
                            <FormGroup check>
                                <Label check>
                                    <Input type="checkbox" />{' '}
                                    APAC
                                </Label>
                            </FormGroup>
                            <FormGroup check>
                                <Label check>
                                    <Input type="checkbox" />{' '}
                                    UK
                                </Label>
                            </FormGroup>
                            <FormGroup check>
                                <Label check>
                                    <Input type="checkbox" />{' '}
                                    Canada
                                </Label>
                            </FormGroup>
                            <FormGroup check>
                                <Label check>
                                    <Input type="checkbox" />{' '}
                                    Central and Eastern Europe
                                </Label>
                            </FormGroup>
                            <FormGroup check>
                                <Label check>
                                    <Input type="checkbox" />{' '}
                                    Germany
                                </Label>
                            </FormGroup>
                            <FormGroup check>
                                <Label check>
                                    <Input type="checkbox" />{' '}
                                    France
                                </Label>
                            </FormGroup>
                            <FormGroup check>
                                <Label check>
                                    <Input type="checkbox" />{' '}
                                    Greater China
                                </Label>
                            </FormGroup>
                            <FormGroup check>
                                <Label check>
                                    <Input type="checkbox" />{' '}
                                    India
                                </Label>
                            </FormGroup>
                            <FormGroup check>
                                <Label check>
                                    <Input type="checkbox" />{' '}
                                    Japan
                                </Label>
                            </FormGroup>
                            <FormGroup check>
                                <Label check>
                                    <Input type="checkbox" />{' '}
                                    LATAM
                                </Label>
                            </FormGroup>
                            <FormGroup check>
                                <Label check>
                                    <Input type="checkbox" />{' '}
                                    MEA
                                </Label>
                            </FormGroup>
                            <FormGroup check>
                                <Label check>
                                    <Input type="checkbox" />{' '}
                                    United States
                                </Label>
                            </FormGroup>
                            <FormGroup check>
                                <Label check>
                                    <Input type="checkbox" />{' '}
                                    Western Europe
                                </Label>
                            </FormGroup>
                            <Button><NavLink to="/Confirm">Submit</NavLink></Button>
                        </Form>

          </Row>
        </Container>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ConnCust;
```

Image of second issue which seems to correlate with the first issue:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is great place to take advantage of the ability to create custom react components. I would make a new component that is a custom checkbox (based on the one from reactstrap) with the functionality you describe which you can then import into your original document like any other component!

Comment: thanks for suggestions. If I create a custom component, would that just incoude the checkbox and textbox which would then only be shown if that checkbox is selected? Do you not think that the DOM tree would get confused if this custom component is generic? How about the unique text? Got any example you could show a Fiddle of?

Comment: You are correct. You would include both and then add the functionality so the textbook would be revealed when the checkbox is active. No the DOM tree should not get confused. If I were you I'd look up some tutorials on how to create custom components in react. It's fairly straightforward once you understand the basics.